# Test complaining NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

Just added `bcrypt` and a `password_digest` column to database. Now I am getting this error. It is saying it doesn't recognize name, this test was passing. Now it is failing. All other tests are passing ( including one of `password_digest`, oddly enough). I am using the  testing framework that comes with rails.

```
  def test_can_create_profiles
    user = create_user('tester@test.com', 'hassan') #creates a profile with randomized password
    assert_equal "hassan", User.find_by_email('tester@test.com').name
  end
```

bundle exec rake test

```
  1) Error:
UserTest#test_can_create_profiles:
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    test/models/user_test.rb:9:in `test_can_create_profiles'



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  before_save {self.email = email.downcase}  
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true,
    :format => { :with => email_regex },
    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive =>
      false }
  has_secure_password
end
```

If there is any information I am missing pelase let me know.

---

```
def create_user(email, name)
  user = User.new(name: name, email: email)
  user.password_digest = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
  user.save
  user
end
```

AGHH

```
x = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>
irb(main):002:0> x.name ='lol'
=> "lol"
irb(main):005:0> x.email = 'apple@ape.com'
=> "apple@ape.com"

irb(main):007:0> x.password_digest = 'lol'
=> "lol"
irb(main):008:0> x.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('apple@ape.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
```

---

Okay so the problem is somewhere over here!

```
irb(main):010:0> raise x.errors.inspect
RuntimeError: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f6fae5b3bf8 @base=#<User id: nil, name: "lol", email: "apple@ape.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "lol">, @messages={:password=>["can't be blank"]}>

irb(main):013:0> raise x.password= 'hello'
RuntimeError: hello
    from (irb):13
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):014:0> raise x.errors.inspect
RuntimeError: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f6fae5b3bf8 @base=#<User id: nil, name: "lol", email: "apple@ape.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$CMPQdQSLKQTS5r0G2a1oheDhblzxcp65KxStZbKKAHmy...">, @messages={:password=>["can't be blank"]}>
    from (irb):14
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1
```

ugh : c

Why is this happening?

EDIT : bcrypt requires a password and password_confirmation field to be filled in.

That was what was causing trouble, as well as a broken test. >.<

Comment: Show us your create_user method - it looks like it is creating invalid user which is not being saved to a database.

Comment: You're right it isn't saving. I just tried to do it from console! : c
don't know why

Comment: add `raise user.errors.inspect` after `user.save` and you should see why. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `create_user` method successfully saves a `User` object, your problem is simple:

You're saving the email address `tester@test.com` and trying to retrieve `test@test.com`.

If that doesn't fix it, please post your `create_user` method.

Comment: Ah. You are right! However I don't think my method is saving a user... >.<

Comment: @user2783087 you should accept the answer if it worked for you and not  indicate in the question as solved

Answer (score 1):

You have added presence validation on password, hence you need to set it before saving. You are currently setting `password_digest` - you should not do this. Digest is an encrypted password and is generated when assigning a password. Hence:

```
def create_user(email, name)
  user = User.new(name: name, email: email)
  user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
  # user.password_confirmation = user.password     # You might need this as well
  user.save!    # To avoid this kind of errors in the future use banged save
  user
```

end